# What is the two-sided seven sealed scroll?

Tags: john, revelation, isaiah, prophecy, god

I’m seeing numerous answers regarding this, but not one of them includes Isaiah 28/29.

What is on the seven-sealed two-sided scroll?

What if not His own Word, would be in God’s Right Hand?

A double-edged (two-sided) flaming sword comes out of the mouth of the Angel. What if not Holy Words come from the Angel’s mouth?

A double-sided scroll is in the Right Hand of the One sitting on the throne.

In Isaiah 29 the sealed scroll is described as “The vision of all”. From the creation to the judgment/end. God’s Word.

In Isaiah 28/29 the prophecy of the sealed scroll is given.

Isaiah 29:10-18 KJV

> <sup>**10**</sup> For the Lord hath poured out upon you the spirit of deep sleep, and hath closed your eyes: the prophets and your rulers, the seers hath he covered. <sup>**11**</sup> And the vision of all is become unto you as the words of a book that is sealed, which men deliver to one that is learned, saying, Read this, I pray thee: and he saith, I cannot; for it is sealed: <sup>**12**</sup> And the book is delivered to him that is not learned, saying, Read this, I pray thee: and he saith, I am not learned. <sup>**13**</sup> Wherefore the Lord said, Forasmuch as this people draw near me with their mouth, and with their lips do honour me, but have removed their heart far from me, and their fear toward me is taught by the precept of men: <sup>**14**</sup> Therefore, behold, I will proceed to do a marvellous work among this people, even a marvellous work and a wonder: for the wisdom of their wise men shall perish, and the understanding of their prudent men shall be hid. <sup>**15**</sup> Woe unto them that seek deep to hide their counsel from the Lord, and their works are in the dark, and they say, Who seeth us? and who knoweth us? <sup>**16**</sup> Surely your turning of things upside down shall be esteemed as the potter's clay: for shall the work say of him that made it, He made me not? or shall the thing framed say of him that framed it, He had no understanding? <sup>**17**</sup> Is it not yet a very little while, and Lebanon shall be turned into a fruitful field, and the fruitful field shall be esteemed as a forest? <sup>**18**</sup> And in that day shall the deaf hear the words of the book, and the eyes of the blind shall see out of obscurity, and out of darkness.

Daniel is told when the sealed scroll will be unsealed... at the time of the end.

Even John in Revelation is told to seal up what the seven thunders uttered. Because it will be revealed at the time of the end which wasn’t his time. He was told it pertained to the hereafter, after his time.

It is God’s Word which is the plan of salvation.

Only the Lamb with seven eyes (complete understanding) and seven horns (complete authority) can unseal it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to the group @7eyesopenwide. Your question requires clarification. You are apparently referring to the scroll mentioned in Revelation but do not provide a reference.  Also, are you presuming that the various scroll as the same, or is that part of your question? Do you include the scroll of Ezek. 2-3 in the question? More generally, please provide specific references rather than referring to the name of a book (Daniel, Revelation) without chapter and verse.

Comment: This question needs clarification.  Are you asking about the interpretation of Rev 5 & 6?  If so, why restrict yourself to Isa 29:11?  What not also include Dan 12:4, Jer 32:10, 44, Isa 8:16, etc?